# GLSL getting location of fragment shader variable and put glm::vec3 data to glUniform3fv()

Tags: opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have variable in fragment shader

```
struct Light
{
  vec3 lightColor;
  vec3 ambientIntensity;
  vec3 direction;
  vec3 diffuseIntensity;
};

Light light;
```

I wanted to get variable location and put data into this with code presented below:

```
vec3 ambientIntensity(1,1,1);
...
GLuint ambientIntensityLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"light.ambientIntensity");
if(ambientIntensityLocation==-1)
    return false;
glUniform3fv(ambientIntensityLocation,1,&ambientIntensity[0]);
```

This code return with false value.

I have two questions:

- Can I generally get location of variable from FS or I have to pass it
  with VS
- Is passing vec3 to glUniform3fv() correct?

[EDIT] I give my shaders code:

VS Code:

```
#version 400 core

layout(location=0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location=2) in vec3 normal;

out vec2 uv;
out vec3 norm;

uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vertexPosition,1.0);
  uv = vertexUV;
  norm = (Model*vec4(normal,0.0)).xyz;
}
```

FS Code:

```
#version 400 core

struct Light
{
  vec3 lightColor;
  vec3 ambientIntensity;
  vec3 direction;
  vec3 diffuseIntensity;
};

uniform Light light;

in vec2 uv;
in vec3 norm;

out vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D texSamp;

void main()
{
  color = texture(texSamp,uv).rgb*light.ambientIntensity;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can get the location of an FS variable but it is a lot of work. It will involve calling a GL 4.3 / [`GL_ARB_program_interface_query`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/program_interface_query.txt) function: [`glGetProgramResourceiv (...)`](http://opengl.anteru.net/glGetProgramResource.xhtml) using `GL_REFERENCED_BY_FRAGMENT_SHADER`. However, I do not think you actually care about any FS variables here, uniforms are per-program not per-stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I generally get location of variable from FS or I have to pass it with VS

Yes you can directly get it. Uniforms are per *prorgram* state, not per shader stage. Any shaders linked to a program can access the uniforms.

> Is passing vec3 to glUniform3fv() is correct?

Yes.

> This code return with false value.

You don't ask why this might be the case, but I still can make the succestion that this is due to the fact that this uniform is actually not *active*, so not influencing the output of zour shader and hence optimised out. However, that is just a guess. You should post your shader code if you want a more reliable explanation for that.